# Obtener la fecha actual con la hora 00:00:00 en Java

Tags: java, date, calendar

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

Con eso obtengo la fecha actual, pero quiero saber si hay alguna forma de que la hora sea 00:00:00 en vez de cuando se llamó a ese método.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes poner la hora que quieras a mano. En tu caso sería:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Y al final tienes lo que quieres con lo mismo para tener la `Date`:

```
c.getTime();
```

La salida que te da sería:

> Wed Dec 07 00:00:00 CET 2016

Comment: Solo falta agregar los milisegundos para que sea realmente 0:00:00 ya que si lo necesita para un TIMESTAMP los milisegundos pueden darle diferentes resultados. Saludos.

Comment: Puede ser, pero como en la pregunta pone 0:0:0 lo he dejado así. Supongo que cuando vea tu comentario a lo mejor se lo plantea @Ajeno .

Comment: Excelente, me sirvió tu respuesta, Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando Java 8 (`java.time`):

❑ *Código*:

```
ZoneId zona = ZoneId.systemDefault();
LocalDate ahora = LocalDate.now();
ZonedDateTime inicioHoy = ahora.atStartOfDay(zona);
Instant instante = inicioHoy.toInstant();
Date fecha = Date.from(instante);

System.out.println(zona);
System.out.println(ahora);
System.out.println(inicioHoy);
System.out.println(instante);
System.out.println(fecha);
```

```
// En una línea
Date fecha = Date.from(LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(zona).toInstant());
```

❑ *Salida*:

```
America/Mexico_City
2016-12-07
2016-12-07T00:00-06:00[America/Mexico_City]
2016-12-07T06:00:00Z
Wed Dec 07 00:00:00 CST 2016
```

Para saber más, véase [*Java SE 8 Date and Time*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html).

Answer (score 2):

Hola Con JAVA 8 lo puedes hacer asi :

```
LocalDateTime fechaHora LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0))
//teniendo el resultado : 2017-02-07T00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

`Calendar.HOUR` utiliza 0-11 (para su uso con AM / PM).

Número de campo para `Get` y `Set` indicando la hora de la mañana o por la tarde.

HORA se utiliza para el reloj de 12 horas (0 - 11).

Mediodía y la medianoche están representados por 0, no por 12.

Ejemplo:

```
package mx.com.softmolina;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 *
 * @author SoftMolina
 */

public class SetTime {

    static SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 17);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 2);
        System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

    }

}
```

Resultado: `08-12-2016 05:30:02`

En el ejemplo anterior como pueden apreciar, le estamos indicando que nos muestra la hora de las 5 de la tarde con 30 minutos y 2 segundos.

http://blog.softmolina.com.mx/wp/2016/12/07/establecer-el-tiempo-a-un-objeto-de-fecha-en-java/